# how to suspend other nonrelated processes to allow a proces in interest to occupy the CPU?

Tags: process

Is it possible to

- first find out what processes are necessary to run a process in interest, and
- then suspend all other unrelated processes to allow the process in interest to use the CPU as much as possible
- when the process in interest finishes running, resume the suspended processes?

For example,  a process in interest is djview

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That should be possible (at least for many cases) if there is a permanent connection. Then you can check `/proc/PID/fd` for sockets and FIFOs (more difficult if regular files are used) and find the processes belonging to them.

But I would not block the other processes completely; that seems dangerous. It may cause deadlocks if you make a mistake (and may cause other problems).

I suggest to dump the CPU and I/O priority of all processes, adapt them (`renice`, `ionice`) and restore them afterwards. That may cost the main process 10% performance but you are on the safe side.